# Excluding file types from Kendo Upload

Tags: asp.net, kendo-ui

I am trying to set up Kendo upload validation. I am able to set it up such that it will accept only listed files, but I would like to flip that around. I want to be able to specify file types that are not allowed.  For example, if I want to exclude `.exe` file types, I specify `.exe` in the code.

Below is the code I currently have that specifies a *white list* of file types allowed; but I would like to use a *blacklist* for validation.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Upload()
  .Name("files")
  .TemplateId("fileTemplate")
  .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "no-auto-save", AutoComplete = "off" })
    .Async(a => a.Save("AddAttachments", "Transaction").AutoUpload(false))
    .Events(e => e.Upload("uploadAttachments").Success("attachmentsUploaded"))
    .Validation(validation => validation.AllowedExtensions(new string[] { ".doc", ".docx", ".ppt", ".pptx", ".xls", ".xlsx", ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png", ".html", ".gif", "txt", ".pdf", ".json", ".zip" }))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a handler for event `upload`

Component declaration

```
.Events(events => events
    .Upload("onUpload")
)
```

Event handling JavaScript

```
function onUpload(e) {
  if (e.files[0].extension == ".exe") {
    e.preventDefault();
  }      
}
```

See

- https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/api/Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent/UploadBuilder
- https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/upload/events/upload

> ```
> function onUpload(e) {
>     // An array with information about the uploaded files
>     var files = e.files;
>
>     // Checks the extension of each file and aborts the upload if it is not .jpg
>     $.each(files, function () {
>         if (this.extension.toLowerCase() != ".jpg") {
>             alert("Only .jpg files can be uploaded")
>             e.preventDefault();
>         }
>     });
> ```